# Find a subset of a set of vectors such that the difference between the maximum and minimum element of the sum of the subset is minimal

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem, greedy

The length of each vector is equal to 3. The number of vectors is no more than 300 and sum of the sum of all vectors is no more than 500.

Example:

For set of vectors: `[0, 0, 1], [2, 3, 4], [0, 5, 0], [10, 5, 9]` the desired subset will be `[0, 0, 1], [0, 5, 0], [10, 5, 9]` because its sum is `[0 + 0 + 10, 0 + 5 + 5, 1 + 0 + 9] = [10, 10, 10]` so the difference between maximal element (10) and minimal element (10) of vector is `10 - 10 = 0`.

Another example:

Set of vectors: `[2, 3, 2], [6, 6, 2], [4, 3, 3], [3, 5, 0]`. Desired subset: `[2, 3, 2], [4, 3, 3]`. (The sum of desired subset is `[6, 6, 5]` and the difference between sums maximal and minimal element is `6 - 5 = 1`).

I've tried greedy algorithm: sorting the set of vectors and then iterating through it adding another vector to the sum if it reduces the difference between maximal and minimal element of sum. But it doesn't always work properly. I feel like I need some sort of modified knapsack problem algorithm but don't know how to stick it to solution.

Comment: This problem is NP hard, so there must be more constraints than you aren't reproducing in your question. For example, perhaps all the elements of the vectors are small, positive integers?

Comment: @PaulHankin Yes, no more than 300 vectors and also sum of the sum of all vectors is no more than 500 (so if you add up all vectors from set and find the sum of elements of this vector it will be no more than 500)

Comment: @PaulHankin Actually in the initial problem you are given a list of strings consisting of characters 'a', 'b' and 'c' (e.g. "aabbbcc", "aaaaaabbbbbbcc", "aaaabbbccc", "aaabbbbb"). You need to choose such strings from list that the difference between the symbol with the largest number of occurrences and the symbol with the smallest number of occurrences will be minimal.

Comment: Represent vector sums as (b-a, c-a) and incrementally compute all possible sums? There's at most 1001x1001 possible sums -- b-a and c-a range from -500 to 500 -- so computing all possible sums of vectors can be done in around 300 million steps.

Comment: @PaulHankin Sorry, but I'm not sure if I got you. How do I choose what to add up to vector sums? And how do I compute all possible sums?

Comment: @PaulHankin Also do you mean difference between characters occurrences in (b - a, c - a) or not?

Comment: Yes, so for example `aaaaaabbbbbbcc` is represented as (0, -4).

Comment: @PaulHankin Could you please explain your idea in more details? I understand I can represent set of vectors `[2, 3, 2], [6, 6, 2], [4, 3, 3], [3, 5, 0]` like this `(-1, 0), (0, -4), (-1, -1), (-2, -3)`. What do I need iterate through? From `(b - a)` to `(c - a)` for each vector? And if I do, how to I compute the result though?

Comment: @PaulHankin I am pretty sure that my code is your idea.  It requires more than 300 million steps though - 300 million is the size of the dictionary but you wind up trying to put items into it hundreds of times.

Comment: @btilly The size of the dict should be approx 1 million given that sums never exceed 500.

Comment: @PaulHankin The sums of one dimension are -500 to 500.  That's a range of 1000.  And a thousand times a thousand rises to a million.  But after 300 arrays, the range potentially rises to 300,000.  The same calculation now gives us 90 billion.  But the dimensions are not independent, and few of the arrays will be extreme.  I consider 300 million to be in the range of a reasonable number of values actually encountered.  But now we can arrive at a combination of values in many ways.  Hence my comment.

Comment: That said, we can speed this up by stopping immediately if we find `(0, 0)`.  Which can probably happen in lots and lots of ways.

Comment: @btilly I read "the sum of all vectors is no more than 500" to mean that the total number of each character is all the strings is at most 500, not a limit per string.

Comment: @PaulHankin Oh, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is working code based on the idea presented in the comments by Paul Hankin.

```
def min_comb (vectors):
    if not len(vectors):
        return None

    last_vector_idx = {}
    idx = -1
    finished = False
    for vector in vectors:
        if finished:
            break
        idx += 1
        next_vector_idx = last_vector_idx.copy()
        short = (vector[1] - vector[0], vector[2] - vector[0])
        if short not in next_vector_idx:
            next_vector_idx[short] = idx
            if short == (0, 0):
                finished = True
                last_vector_idx = next_vector_idx
                break
        for prev_short in last_vector_idx.keys():
            next_short = (prev_short[0] + short[0], prev_short[1] + short[1])
            if next_short not in next_vector_idx:
                next_vector_idx[next_short] = idx
                if short == (0, 0):
                    finished = True
                    last_vector_idx = next_vector_idx
                    break
        last_vector_idx = next_vector_idx

    k = 0
    while True:
        for i in range(-k, k+1):
            for j in range(max(0, i) - k, min(0, i) + k+1):
                if (i, j) in last_vector_idx:
                    answer = []
                    short = (i, j)
                    while 0 == len(answer) or not short == (0, 0):
                        vector = vectors[last_vector_idx[short]]
                        answer.append(vector)
                        short = (short[0] + vector[0] - vector[1], short[1] + vector[0] - vector[2])
                    return list(reversed(answer))
        k += 1

vectors = [[0, 0, 1], [2, 3, 4], [0, 5, 0], [10, 5, 9]]
print(min_comb(vectors))
```

Comment: I don't think your selection of the smallest vector is right in the second part. (2, 3) is a better solution than (-2, 2).

Comment: @PaulHankin Good point, I think I fixed that.